# i can´t use GlobalErrorHandler as Injectable(), and launch it when lazy funcion child Not Found?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-errorhandler

problem

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk dashboard.module failed.
Error: Loading chunk dashboard.module failed.
```

i would like use this

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  
  handleError(err: any): void {
    const chunkFailedMessage = /Loading chunk [\d]+ failed/;
    const chunkFailedMessage1 = /Loading chunk dashboard.module failed/;

    console.log('Loading chunk FRT'+ err);
    console.log('Loading chunk FRT'+ err.message);
    if (chunkFailedMessage1.test(err.message)) {
      alert("Se requiere un reinicio para el correcto funcionamiento del sitio");
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
}
```

i have in my proyect app.modules.ts --> pages.module.ts --> Child (module who should lauch ErrorHandler)

Comment: Absolutely right, that was my miss understanding

Answer (score 0):

In your module, you should register `GlobalErrorHandler` in providers as below,

```
 providers:[{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler }]
```